# web service calls mvc crud system

Tags: java, web-services, crud

I have a good/normal working mvc crud application in java. For example, if I want to get all the products, the productcontroller calls the productservice layer, it calls the productdao which makes a connection to the database, gets all the products and gives it back via the same way.

Now I must make a web service that uses this crud application. Let say the web service has to get all the products. I allready made an web service interface and implemantation. I made a sun-jaxws.xml where I describe the endpoint. I made a web service client where I create the URL, QName, service.create and getPort. The normal stuff to make it done. But I'm stuck here, I dont know how to call the crud application system. In my webserviceimpl class, I @autowired (because I use spring3) the service layer (productService), and in my method I call the productService.getProducts method. Normally this method calls the productDao layer and so on. But I get a nullpointerexception on my webserviceclient, $Proxy19.getProducts(Unknown Source)

So my question is, how can I call my existing crud application via a web service?

Thx

Comment: Can you share some more information about your web service configuration? Is your web service in a separate project or is it in your MVC application? If your web service is in a separate project, you'll need to check if the Spring context listener is added in web.xml. Also, how is your Spring application context configured?

Comment: I was testing it by making a ws package in the same MVC application, just for making it easy for myself, but it has to be a separate project. The MVC application is configured with spring3 and hibernate 4 with mvc:annotation-driven tag. I configured a WSServletContextListener and a WSServlet in my web.xml file.

Comment: So without seeing the actual code and configuration, this will be difficult to answer...
Maybe this will help: you can find the Spring documentation for JAX-WS [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#remoting-web-services-jaxws-export-servlet)